# Unclean shutdown with MongoDB results in corrupted mongod.lock file

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a MongoDB database storing data in a particular directory, and I am using a Node.js process to write to it. Sometimes my Node.js process experiences a forced shutdown (notice the passive voice) and I get this error message, which pretty much means I have to go in and simply delete the .lock file:

```
2015-06-16T11:09:19.004-0700 W -        [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - /Users/amills001c/mongodb_sc_admin_dev_data/mongod.lock is not empty.
2015-06-16T11:09:19.013-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **************
old lock file: /Users/amills001c/mongodb_sc_admin_dev_data/mongod.lock.  probably means unclean shutdown,
but there are no journal files to recover.
this is likely human error or filesystem corruption.
```

What is the best way to prevent this from happening so I don't have to go in and delete the mongod.lock file everytime I start up the database?

Something like this?

```
   process.on('SIGINT', function (msg1,msg2) {
        mongoose.disconnect();
        mongoose.connection.close(function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        });
        console.log('SIGINT message:',msg1,msg2)
    });
```

Comment: Why is your database affected by Node.js's forced shutdown?

Comment: Because the database connection is probably not closed properly - so maybe a good answer to this question would be to create a shutdown hook in node to close the MongoDB connection properly? IDK

Comment: The error says that MongoDB itself shut down improperly, not the connection. Does your DB ever shut down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client connections to MongoDB do not affect the `mongod.lock` file. The error message relates to your DB server aka the `mongod` process shutting down uncleanly. The solution for that is to always shutdown your DB process cleanly.

Unclean shutdown should be an exceptional situation which happens out of your control. If it is happening repeatedly then there is something wrong with the way you are running and managing your `mongod` process. Please check why an unclean shutdown happened and fix that cause.

That said, the client code that you have presented in the question is definitely a good practice too. Closing connection to the DB when quitting is desirable. Please do that also. However it is not related to the `mongod.lock` error message you are seeing. That is purely on the DB server side.

Comment: I see - can I do a ctrl+c to shutdown mongoDB from the command line, or do I need to write some script that shuts it down cleanly?

Comment: That would depend on how you have installed MongoDB. Ubuntu packages come with upstart scripts. If you have just downloaded a tarball and are running `mongod` interactively Ctrl+C should be good. More details here : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/